# Is there reason to create multiple instances of Ogre::RaySceneQuery for same scene?

Tags: ogre3d, ogre

I wonder if there are any benefits if i use multiple instances of `Ogre::RaySceneQuery` for same scene. Or if there are any things that requires it's own special instance?

Comment: You won't have to pay for initialization overhead multiple times. I doubt that's really significant though. I wouldn't worry about it unless you're having memory or performance issues

Answer (score 1):

Usually you only perform one query at one time, so there's no need to use a new RSQ instance each time.
Even if you're doing multiple types of queries you have to give the RSQ a new ray each time, so there won't be any difference if you do this using one or more instances.

Usually the code looks something like this:

```
Ogre::SceneManager* mSceneMgr;
Ogre::Ray ray; //whatever you want to query

Ogre::RaySceneQuery* mRaySceneQuery = mSceneMgr->createRayQuery(Ogre::Ray());
mRaySceneQuery->setRay(ray);
Ogre::RaySceneQueryResult &result = mRaySceneQuery->execute();

//loop through the result
```

For each new ray you want to test you have to give the RSQ the new ray. Usually the rays are dependent on some coordinates (the player, the camera, ...) and you have to update the rays each iteration.

In case you have a *static ray*, a ray which doesn't depend on something and will be the same vector each and every iteration you may save the call to `setRay(Ogre::Ray)` if you use another RSQ instance for this specific ray only, but i doubt that this will be a huge performance boost or even noticeable as you still have to execute the query.

---

There's another point you should consider: query masks.
Every entity can have a binary mask which determines if it can get hit by a ray query.
Let's suppose you have this structure

```
enum QueryFlags {
  FRIENDS = 1<<0;
  FOES = 1<<1;
}
```

and every frame you wanna test if something hit a friend and/or a foe. There are a few possibilities:

You may check for both at once with `mRaySceneQuery->setQueryMask(FRIENDS | FOES)` and check every retrieved result if it is a friend or a foe.
You may `execute` two queries, one for `FRIENDS` and a second for the `FOES`.
You may use two RSQs, one for the friends and a second for the foe. This way you save a call to `setQueryMask` each time. As above I doubt this will give a significant performance gain, but I prefer the last option.